# Clients growth over time MDX

Tags: mdx

I want to calculate the clients growth over the time.
So every day i have the total clients per state and per product subscription, and i can calculate the total for every day.
If i want to calculate the growth every day i don't have problems because i use a calculated member with

`[Date].CurrentMember-[Date].PrevMember`

This works pretty fine, but now i want to calculate the growth  on month. So i have to sum all day growths of the month to calculate the month growth, right?

But my problem is that i'm too newbie to MDX and i can't find a way to produce that result (I want to know how many clients i have more or less over the year).
My intuition says that i need to sum all day's growth in the agregate date.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If your date hierarchy has a month level above the date level (eg. Year-Month-Day), your cube will already have pre-processed this value. I would use [`ANCESTOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145616.aspx) and [`LAG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144866.aspx) to get the data for a given day's month:

```
WITH MEMBER [Date].[YMD].[Current Month] AS 
       ANCESTOR(
         [Date].[YMD].CurrentMember,
         [Date].[YMD].[Month Level]
       )

     MEMBER [Date].[YMD].[Growth this month] AS
       (
         [Date].[YMD].[Current Month]
         -
         [Date].[YMD].[Current Month].LAG(1)
       )
```

This will, however, only get the data from a whole-month period.

If what you're after is *all the data between a particular day and the same day in the previous month*, then [`PARALLELPERIOD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145500.aspx) is your go-to function (sidenote: not a [`goto` statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto)). `PARALLELPERIOD(Level, N, Member)` will look at the position of `Member` amongst its siblings, then go to its ancestor at `Level`, go `N` members prior to that, and traverse back down to a member in the same relative position as `Member`.

In other words, it looks up your date in a prior month, year or whatev'.

```
WITH MEMBER [Date].[YMD].[One Month Ago Today] AS
       PARALLELPERIOD(
         [Date].[YMD].[Calendar Month],
         1,
         [Date].[YMD].CurrentMember
       )

     MEMBER [Date].[YMD].[All data since today last month] AS
       (
         /* The [Member]:[Member] syntax here is a range */
         [Date].[YMD].[One Month Ago Today] : [Date].[YMD].CurrentMember
       )

     MEMBER [Date].[YMD].[Two Months Ago Today] AS
       PARALLELPERIOD(
         [Date].[YMD].[Calendar Month],
         2,
         [Date].[YMD].CurrentMember
       )

     MEMBER [Date].[YMD].[All data between today last month and today in the previous month] AS
       (
         [Date].[YMD].[Two Months Ago Today] : [Date].[YMD].[One Month Ago Today]
       )

     MEMBER [Date].[YMD].[Growth in the last month since the previous month] AS
       (
         [Date].[YMD].[All data between today last month and today in the previous month]
         -
         [Date].[YMD].[All data since today last month]
       )
```

Hope this helps.

<3